# Open Source Linux system benchmark software

Tags: linux, performance, benchmarking

How can I run a system benchmark in a Linux installation? I'd like to do a full test with the core system functionalities like:

- CPU performance
- Memory performance
- Disk / IO performance
- Network performance

Is there any Open Source tool that I can run in a server and collect benchmark data?

Answer (score 2):

Check out

http://openbenchmarking.org/

They have a lot of good information about Open OS Benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

I find [sysbench](http://manpg.es/sysbench) pretty useful.

On my cloud machines, I often run:

```
for i in cpu threads mutex memory; do
        sysbench --test=$i run
done
```

Note that there are many, many test options, and two more modes that require a bit more setup ([fileio](http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/docs/#fileio_mode) and [oltp](http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/docs/#database_mode)).

I use this to determine the relative speed of various instances I launch with my cloud providers.

Answer (score 0):

the [DaCapo Benchmark Suite](http://dacapobench.org/), is Java based, but a great mix of different applications.

or for single thread CPU Performance: `time echo "scale=5000; a(1)*4" | bc -l`
(from [tuxshell](http://tuxshell.blogspot.com/2009/08/bc-as-cpu-benchmark.html))